# получение дочерных процессов, которые запускает основной процесс

Tags: java, процесс, runtime

имеется процесс  `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c %s", command ));`

данный процесс порождает другие процессы, например, из `bat` вызывается `java ...`, который выполняется, как другой процесс.

Если из консоли `CMD` терминейтить, то все процессы останавливаются, если выполнить `process.destroy()`, то останавливается `CMD`, а сам java-процесс висит.

Как получить средствами `java` "дочерние" процессы, которые плодит сущность `process`?

Comment: Обратите внимание на [ответ на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6356410/4182275), в частности на часть _be aware that if the process that you invoke creates new sub-processes, those may not be terminated_. Т.о. возможно вы наткнулись на [баг](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4770092) упомянутый в этом ответа.

Comment: хм. может в этом и проблема.